# Applications of mono-anabelian geometry

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I'm about to start learning some anabelian geometry.
I've come across some papers discussing 'mono-anabelian' geometry. 
I think it sounds interesting.. as I do not yet have a strong background in this field yet, I don't really know what 'mono-anabelian' geometry is able to solve, that "usual" anabelian geometry might not.

So here's the question[s]:
What are the most 'well-known/important' applications of mono-anabelian geometry?

Using the notational conventions of Mochizuki: Are there (interesting) results using mono-anabelian geometry in a way, that seems to be not applicable by 'bi-anabelian' methods?

I'd be interested in papers/articles, keywords to look for etc.

Also: Is mono-anabelian stuff widely 'acknowledged' by the anabelian geometry research community?

As it is related: What would be a good place to start learning about anabelian geometry?
Like: What papers, scripts, books, lecture notes, ...,  could one start looking into?
(Assuming a basic knowledge of algebraic geometry, class field theory, also a really (really!) basic understanding of the etale fundamental group)

Answer (score 1):

Let me remind you the first result in anabelian geometry, i.e. Neukirch-Uchida theorem, which states that: Given an isomorphism of absolute Galois groups of number fields, there exists a unique isomorphism of corresponding number fields. This is a bi-anabelian result, roughly speaking bi-anabelian means that given an isomorphism of two objects and end up with an isomorphism of two objects. Yuichiro Hoshi developed the following result: Given an absolute Galois group of a number field, one can reconstruct the number field by using a group theoretic algorithm. This is a mono-anabelian result corresponds Neukirch-Uchida theorem. So you can regard mono-anabelian result as an algorithm to really "compute" corresponding bi-anabelian result.

[Mono-anabelian reconstruction of number fields](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/handle/2433/244782) by Hoshi is about the mono-anabelian algorithm of Neukirch-Uchida theorem, the paper is fairly self-contained, if you know the proof of Neukirch-Uchida theorem, you should not have too much difficulties on this paper.

If you want to start learning anabelian geometry, you should first look at *Cohomology of Number Fields* by Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg, the final chapter gives you a very good introduction of anabelian geometry, and the proof methodologies in bi-anabelian geometry. Technically, after reading the proof of Neukirch-Uchida theorem, you can go to the mono-anabelian result by Hoshi, or go to further generalizations of Neukirch-Uchida theorem, for example the [function field case](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-9Iznibr2AhVPUMAKHRtXAn0QFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F1971069&usg=AOvVaw0JuobJEBAsq9GtTR24F6l8)(replace number fields by function fields) or the [maximal solvable case](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-9Iznibr2AhVPUMAKHRtXAn0QFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2FjournalArticle%2FDownload%3Furlid%3D10.2748%252Ftmj%252F1178229803&usg=AOvVaw0cDYp5hy1GKaY5boH-6keq) (replace absolute Galois groups by its maximal solvable quotients), both generalizations are proven by Uchida.

What I have mentioned are all about the isom-form of anabelian geometry, there are also hom-form, which is much more difficult, a lot of problems have not been solved yet.

I hope this helps.